# Software to access my development server over internet - ubuntu

Tags: linux, remote-access, web-server

friends I need to access my development server over the internet. Is there any software for that?

**SetUp** : We have a Linux server (a PC with ubuntu and LAMP server installed) which we access using putty in office (connected using LAN), but now we have to open that server for access from outside the office I,e remote access.

Is there a software so that I can install it on my  server so that I can access the server from my home?

Comment: What do you mean by access? just upo/downloadd fiels? Take over the desktop & develop software remotelyl?

Comment: @Mawg ya I want to ssh (using putty or notepad++ FTP plugin ) the server and use it for developing  application. like localhost

Comment: So you've just named the tool: ssh. Comes in the repo of every distribution (usually `openssh` as client and as server package. Or did I miss something? What does "like localhost" mean? Console? GUI?

Comment: @Izzy localhost means- i want to use this software for web application development, so i should have function to load my application in browser using a link same as we use `localhost/myapplication` for developing with xampp.

Comment: SSH offers that. You could ask at SuperUser for how to achieve it – after searching if it wasn't already asked: [Reverse tunnel commands through ssh?](http://superuser.com/q/322757/143340) The feature you're looking for is "remote forwarding". [Forward remote port to remote host](http://superuser.com/q/692375/143340), [more](http://superuser.com/search?q=[ssh]+remote+forward+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 1):

[OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) server / client.

Basically it works like this : on your work computer you install the server. Then connect securely from home (it creates an encrypted tunnel between you and your work server). After you are connected, you have a new "virtual lan" and you can connect through any software you desire to your work computer. You can SSH/VNC/etc everything is tunneled through the secure connection established with OpenVPN.